# Importing beta developer story back to SO careers

Tags: discussion, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

A few weeks ago I signed up for the Stack Overflow developer story beta. I started by importing my existing Jobs/Careers (I'm confused as its name is the current name of the existing jobs site) CV and then spent a good amount of time updating my profile and making sure everything was up-to-date. I like the new format and really like the CV that it generates. (Thanks for removing the SO logo from the PDF!)

A few weeks ago I was doing this mostly for fun; I wasn't actively looking for a job. However, in the world of tech startups things change quickly and I am now actively looking. I started my search using the current Jobs/Careers site and noticed, when I went to write prospective employers, it looked like my old and outdated Jobs/Careers CV was being sent along with my application instead of my shiny new developer story.

I understand this is in beta, but I'm a bit confused as to how "public" developer story profiles are.

Are they currently accessible by employers? I also know it's possible to import from an existing Jobs/Careers CV, but if the developer story isn't currently accessible, is there any way to go the other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this initial phase, we are not yet showing developer stories to employers. That said, the next step is gradually allowing users to make their developer story visible to employers instead of the old CV.

It's something we are working on *right now* and should be out this week or early next week.